# PHP code to generate vendor code from the first letters of form data

Tags: php

I want vendor_code to be VHSJS050814 where VH is the prefix, S is the first letter of form data 'city' and JS is the first letter of 'first_name' and 'last_name' of form data and 050814 is the currrent date. My php codes is furnished below. When I submit the form, I am not getting any data saved in Vendor_code in the database but other fields are getting saved. Please can anyone help me where I am going wrong?

HTML FORM:

```
<form action="process.php" method="post" name="form1" id="form1" class="register" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <fieldset class="row1">
            <legend>SECTION 1: MEMBER CONTACT DETAILS
            </legend>
            <p>
                <label>Title *
                </label>
                <select class="title" name="title">
                    <option>
                    </option>
                  <option>Mr.
                    </option>
                  <option>Mrs.
                    </option>
                  <option>Miss.
                    </option>
                  <option>Ms.
                    </option>
                </select>
                <label>
                </label>
                <input type="hidden" name="date_of_joining" value="<?php echo date("d.m.y");?>"/>

              </p>
              <p>
                <label>First Name *
                </label>
                <input type="text" name="first_name"/>
                <label>
                </label>
                <input type="hidden" name="vendor_code" value=""/>
      </p>
                <p>
                <label>Last Name *
                </label>
                <input type="text" name="last_name"/>

                <label>phone 1
                </label>
                <input type="text" name="phone1"/>
            </p>
            <p>
               <label>Date of Birth
               </label>
               <input placeholder="mm-dd-yy" type="text" name="dob"/>
               <label>phone 2
              </label>
                <input type="text" name="phone2"/>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Address *
                </label>
                <input type="text" class="long" name="address"/>
                <label>Mobile 1 *
                </label>
                <input type="text" name="mobile1"/>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>State/City *
                </label>
                <input type="text" class="long" name="city"/>
                <label>Mobile 2
                </label>
                <input type="text" name="mobile2"/>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Post Code *
                </label>
              <input type="text" name="postal_code"/>
                <label>Email 1 *
                </label>
                <input type="text" class="long" name="email1"/>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Country *
                </label>
                <input type="text" name="country"/>
                <label>Email 2
                </label>
                <input type="text" class="long" name="email2"/>
            </p>
            <p>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="row1">
            <legend>SECTION 2: MEMBER ADDITIONAL DETAILS
            </legend>
            <p>
                <label>Company Name *
                </label>
              <input type="text" name="company_name"/>
                <label>Company Details
                </label>
              <input placeholder="Please mention" type="text" name="company_details"/>
            </p>    
            <p>
                <label>Company Address *
                </label>
              <input type="text" class="long" name="company_address"/>
                <label>Area of Product *
                </label>
              <input placeholder="you deal into e.g. Womens Wear" type="text" class="long" name="area_of_products"/>

            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Website
                </label>
                <input value="http://www." type="text" name="website"/>
                <label>Nationality
                </label>
              <input type="text" class="long" name="nationality"/>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Country of Res.
                </label>
              <input type="text" name="country_of_res"/>
                <label>Member Type
                </label>
              <input type="text" class="long" name="member_type"/>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Identity Proof
                </label>
                <select name="id_proof">
                    <option>
                    </option>
                  <option>Voter ID
                    <option>Passport
                    <option>Adhaar Card
                    </option>
                </select>
              <input name="file_idproof" type="file"/>
            </p>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="row4">
            <p class="agreement">
                <input type="checkbox" value="" name="policies"/>
                <label>*  I accept the <a href="required/t&c.htm?KeepThis=true&TB_iframe=true&height=500&width=600" class="thickbox" title="Terms & Policies">Terms and Policies</a></label>
            </p>
        </fieldset>
        <div><button name="submit" class="button">Register &raquo;</button></div>
        <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="form1" />
    </form>
```

And the code for process.php is here:

```
<?php require_once('connections/formsqlconnection.php'); ?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
  break;
case "double":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
  break;
case "date":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
  break;
case "defined":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
  break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}
$w1=$_POST['city'][0];
$w2=$_POST['first_name'][0];
$w3=$_POST['last_name'][0];
$date = date("dmy");
$vendor_code = "VH" + $w1 + $w2 + $w3 + $date;

if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form1")) {
  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO vendor_details (vendor_code, date_of_joining, title, first_name, last_name, dob, address, city, postal_code, country, phone1, phone2, mobile1, mobile2, email1, email2, company_name, company_details, company_address, area_of_product, website, nationality, country_of_res, member_type, id_proof, file_idproof) VALUES ($vendor_code, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['vendor_code'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['date_of_joining'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['title'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['first_name'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['last_name'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['dob'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['address'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['city'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['postal_code'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['country'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['phone1'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['phone2'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['mobile1'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['mobile2'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['email1'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['email2'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['company_name'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['company_details'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['company_address'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['area_of_product'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['website'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['nationality'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['country_of_res'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['member_type'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['id_proof'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_FILES['file_idproof'], "text"));

  mysql_select_db($database_formsqlconnection, $formsqlconnection);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $formsqlconnection) or die(mysql_error());

  $insertGoTo = "confirm.php";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
    $insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  }
  header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));
}
?>
```

Comment: Even though it is not related to your question, let me recommend using PDO (with Prepared Statements) instead of normal mysql functions. They are not really safe and deprecated.

Comment: @MrPixelDream- yes you are right, I will do. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string concat in php is a . not a +, so i think you are trying to do a string concat here.

`$vendor_code = "VH" + $w1 + $w2 + $w3 + $date;`

it should be

```
$vendor_code = "VH" . $w1 . $w2 . $w3 . $date;
```

also you are not adding this string into the database you are using the hidden post var which i don't see being changed at all so I am not sure what data is in it, try changing

```
GetSQLValueString($_POST['vendor_code'], "text"),
```

to

```
GetSQLValueString($vendor_code, "text"),
```

Comment: Thank you...silly mistake......and ya hidden post has no data in it, you are right